# IE Distorts Container

Tags: html, css

The div container `<div class="body-text">` appears completely distorted in IE 10.

As if, it's width was set to 100%. Which is not.

I've never seen this occur before. Could it be fixed?

Please **[Take a look here!](http://test.ample.pw/tta/landing/)**.

**(The page is under construction, and it's still not responsive. So if your screen size is smaller than 1630px in width. Open it in Chrome and zoom out, using "Control" and "-".)**

Thanks.

Comment: ...and where would we find this <div class="body-text"> exactly? you can't expect is to root around your entire page trying to find one specific element.

Comment: Scroll down in the source code. It's rendered as an orange box.

Comment: You have some scary comments in there, according to the validator. Perhaps these are treated differently by different browsers. What if you change them into valid comments, does that help?

Comment: Removed all the comments. Doesn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the developer tools on IE8 you can change the code live, adding a set width, instead of width:auto; for me floated your div back to the right.

Comment: Setting a fixed width did work. Is there anyway I could target this only to IE browsers?

Comment: There are indeed a few ways to do this, Google throws up many websites with info on targeting single browsers. One I refer to is: [link](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/) - this shows how to make the edit within a CSS file, or you can use `<!--[if IE]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" /><![endif]-->`  to add a whole style sheet.

Comment: No problem @Boris If there is a neater way to do this though I've love to hear it.